# Keyword not supported: 'database=multitenant_clienta;trusted_connection'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My program is something like this:-

here I trying to find a data table's data list from specific databases.my goal is:-
assume that this URL I click my browser when I run this application. `https://localhost:44308/ClientA/Contacts` "ClienatA" is the database's name and "Contact" is this database's table name. and I want to show this "Contact" data list.And I already created a database in my SQL server systemically to found this data.I successfully change my connection string name dynamically using a multitenant process.But when I run this application, I found an error. and can't show my specific table data to my view.

Here is my code:-

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-N41V6ER\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MultiTenant_Master;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "TemplateConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-N41V6ER\\SQLEXPRESS;Database==__DBNAME__;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
//other code
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));



            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddCustomerDbContext(Configuration);  //call for main work



            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
//other code
```

CustomerDataContextExtensions.cs

```
 public static class CustomerDataContextExtensions
    {
        public static void AddCustomerDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddScoped(provider =>
            {
                var httpContext = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

                // In this sample we are using a customer identifier as the firs segment in the url request
                // Ex: http://localhost:5000/clienta/contacts
                //     http://localhost:5000/clientb/contacts

                var clientSlug = httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];


               

                var connString = configuration.GetConnectionString("TemplateConnection").Replace("__DBNAME__", $"MultiTenant_{clientSlug}");
                var opts = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
                //opts.UseSqlServer(connString, s => s.EnableRetryOnFailure());
                opts.UseSqlServer(connString,s=>s.EnableRetryOnFailure());
                opts.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

                return new ApplicationDbContext(opts.Options);
            });
        }
    }
```

HomeController

```
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet("/{clientName}/contacts")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetContacts([FromRoute]string clientName)

        {
            var contacts = await _db.Contact.ToListAsync(); //This line actually made this error. I debugged.
            return View();
        }
```

When i run the application,i found this error:-

[image]

How I solve this problem.how I show my specific table's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two equal signs inside your template:

```
Database==__DBNAME__
```

remove the first one:

```
Database=__DBNAME__
```